# Video LAG on Ubuntu 20.04 / Lubuntu 20.04 AMD Athlon 64 3200+ @ 2GHz

Tags: lubuntu, video, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, video-streaming

I'm a noob to Ubuntu. and would appreciate some help

I have this old machine that had **XP**, it was useless, and figured I'd install a light weight OS **Lubuntu** was the Idea. however I continued to install  the only familiar Distro Ubuntu 20.04 with **Lubuntu** over it, I'm not really sure what I did, and with minor problems it is up and running better than expected, but the **video on youtube and on vlc tends to be choppy and lag**, before and after the Lubuntu graphical install--- the sound works great so does everything else.
My idea was to turn this oldie into a media machine, for streaming videos etc.

**I'm ready to do any thing that will accomplish a nice stream.**
here are some specs, hopefully you understand more than I do what I should do

``````
    yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
           ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-40-generic
       .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 2h 36m
     .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 1921
    o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.0.16
   .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1440x900
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: LXQt 0.14.1
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: OpenBox
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: frost
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Arc-Dark [GTK2],  Arc-Dark [GTK3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Papirus-Dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 12G / 148G (9%)
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: AMD Athlon 64 3200+ @ 2GHz
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: AMD/ATI RV370 [Radeon X300/X550/X1050 Series]
                   ````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 1060MiB / 1483MiB

sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo lshw | grep display && sudo lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)
    product: System Product Name
           *-display:0
           *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370 [Radeon X300/X550/X1050 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: GeCube Technologies, Inc. RV370 [Radeon X300/X550/X1050 Series]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25, NUMA node 0
        Memory at d8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Memory at fbdf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeonfb, radeon
``````

Comment: You need hardware acceleration to stream video efficiently, and that machine from 2005 has none. None of the video codecs currently used by youtube were available 15 years ago. You may want to install and run `vainfo` to check its profile, but IMHO, it is unreasonable to expect anything more then light office tasks of such a PC.

Answer (score -1):

For such old timer machine, you better try anything based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. For instance, Linux Mint XFCE flavour.
I believe that newer kernel removed support for old Radeons such as RV370 in your case.

So it's GPU issue, not CPU.

Just try Mint 18.3 (latest in 18. series) and see if it works better, I had similar case.

https://www.linuxmint.com/release.php?id=31

Comment: I doubt this is a good advice. The GPU is supported by the `radeon` driver, but the machine is too old to do video well.